# Using postgres IN clause in golang

Tags: postgresql, go, in-clause

I have been trying to use the postgres IN clause in golang, but keep getting errors. This is the query I want to execute.

```
SELECT id1 FROM my_table WHERE type = (an int) AND id2 = (an int) AND id1 IN (list of UUIDs)
```

I used this code to construct this query but got the following error.

```
var params []interface{}
inCondition := ""
params = append(params, type)
params = append(params, id2)
for _, id := range id1 {
    params = append(params, id)
    if inCondition != "" {
        inCondition += ", "
    }
    inCondition += "?"
}
query := fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT id1 FROM my_table WHERE type = ? AND id2 = ? AND id1 IN (%s)`, inCondition)
rows, err := db.Query(query, params...)
```

Query I got:

```
SELECT id1 FROM my_table WHERE type = ? AND id2 = ? AND id1 IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Params output:

```
[]interface {}=[0 7545449 d323f8d5-ab97-46a3-a34e-95ceac2f3a6a d323f8d5-ab97-46a3-a34e-95ceac2f3a6b d323f8d5-ab97-46a3-a34e-95ceac2f3a6d]
```

Error:

```
pq: syntax error at or near \"AND\""
```

What am I missing? or, how will I get this to work? id1 is a slice of UUIDs whose length is variable.

Comment: *never* use string interpolation for building queries. At least not without carefully quoting everything. This is massive SQL-injection bait. Use bind parameters instead. e.g. https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array

Comment: Are you using [`lib/pq`](https://github.com/lib/pq)? For the parameter's place holder, instead of `?`, try `$1, $2...`.

Comment: Could you show whole result query? May be on database error log. Try to use special interpolation for IN queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ?, using $1,$2 etc as placeholder worked.

Comment: Ya, Postgres doesn't accept the `?` placeholder.  However, if you use [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx), it allows you to use `?` in any language (as well as named paramaters, like `:entry_id`), then remap them to the language in question via `Rebind()`.  Has a bunch of other features that make SQL queries a lot less annoying as well (like the ability to scan directly into a structure).

Answer (score 3):

Ran into a similar issue. Can't remember where exactly I picked this up but I remember still running into issues when dealing with arrays of type integer vs string. What I had to do was to have a local custom type and return a driver compatible value for it. See sample below.

```
// Int64Array is a type implementing the sql/driver/value interface
// This is due to the native driver not supporting arrays...
type Int64Array []int64

// Value returns the driver compatible value
func (a Int64Array) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    var strs []string
    for _, i := range a {
        strs = append(strs, strconv.FormatInt(i, 10))
    }
    return "{" + strings.Join(strs, ",") + "}", nil
}
```

Highly recommend checking out [sqlx](http://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx). Wrote a simple orm wrapper called [papergres](http://github.com/paperchain/papergres) to make my go + postgres life easier :) Give it a try.